# Show that $xyxyxy$ is not a perfect power.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

If $N=xyxyxy$ where $x$ and $y$ are digits.

Show that $N$ cannot be a perfect power, i.e. $N\ne a^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $b>1$.

**My work**

$xy|xyxyxy$
and $\frac{xyxyxy}{xy}=10101$

After factorizing of $10101$ we will get other factors of $xyxyxy$

Factors of $xyxyxy$ : 1, $xy$, 3, 7, 13, 21, 37, 39, 91, 111, 259, 273, 481, 777, 1443, 3367, 10101, $xyxyxy$

If I have missed any factor then please include that.

This is all what I have done, please help me.

Comment: **HInt** One can simplify the argument by focusing on prime factors; which factors of 10101 are prime?

Comment: @Travis Sir the prime factors of 10101 are 3, 7, 13, 37. But how to proceed now please provide few more hints.

Comment: x and y can only be a digit. A perfect n'th power means that the exponents of all factors are a multiple of n...

Comment: @Singh If $N$ is a perfect square, all of its prime factors must occur an even number of times in its prime factorization. What is the smallest number that contains a (positive) even number of factors of $3, 7, 13, 37$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are single digits and $N=xyxyxy$ i.e. $N$ is a six digit number with its first, third and fifth digits equal and second, fourth and sixth digits are equal.

Comment: You should be aware of fundamental theorem of arithmetic, which says every integer has a unique prime factorization. It makes the problem trivial: $\overline{xyxyxy}=(3\cdot 7\cdot 13\cdot 37)\cdot \overline{xy}$ and in a perfect $k$'th power every prime must have an exponent that is a multiple of $k$. The least perfect power $\overline{xyxyxy}$ can be without limitations is $3^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 13^2\cdot 37^2$. but then $\overline{xy}=3\cdot 7\cdot 13\cdot 37$, which is too large to be a 2-digit number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $xyxyxy$ is a $k$-th power, then all primes dividing it must occur at least $k$ times in the factorization.  $10101=3\cdot7\cdot13\cdot37$; so if $10101$ divides $xyxyxy$, you need at least $k-1$ more $3$, $7$, $13$ and $37$'s in the factorization of $xyxyxy/10101 = xy$, which is impossible since $xy$ only has two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Let `dra(n)` represent the additive [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of a number. Digital roots of powers are never 3 or 6 (additionally, 2, 5 and 8 are excluded for squares and 2, 4, 5 and 7 are excluded for cubes). You have showed that `n = xyxyxy` factors as `xy*10101`; since 10101 is not a power -- dra(10101) == 3 -- and 10101 > xy (hence is not a factor of xy) n cannot be written as a power.